# Statement FILEVERSION in VERSIONINFO resource: has it always been defined by four 16-bit integers?

Tags: visual-c++, legacy

I read at [VERSIONINFO resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource) that the statement `FILEVERSION version` has `version` that consists of two 32-bit integers, defined by four 16-bit integers.

Has it always been defined by four 16-bit integers? I have recollections where it was defined by four 8-bit integers but I cannot find evidence supporting it.

Comment: You are not going to find that evidence.  VS_FIXEDFILEINFO has not changed since its introduction in 1993.